# Microsoft Graph on android, responds 404 when retrieving file

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

On microsoft graph explorer i am able to retrieve the excel file easily but when trying on the "active-directory-android-native-v2-master" sample code, it returns 404.

On the the other hand, next line  works and retrieves my information correctly

```
final static String MSGRAPH_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
```

I added all required permissions, got the client ID, run all the sample instructions, read the documentation + stack over flow.

I thought it might be because the link was not coded correctly so i modified the callGraphAPI() method to include:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.
        scheme("https").
        authority("graph.microsoft.com").
        appendPath("v1.0").
        appendPath("drives").
        appendPath(MY_DRIVE).
        appendPath("items").
        appendPath(FILE_ID).
        appendPath("workbook");
String url = builder.build().toString();

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url/*MSGRAPH_URL*/,
        parameters,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
```

but still the same response.

I came across the next stack overflow answer

[404 file not found error when using microsoft graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237248/404-file-not-found-error-when-using-microsoft-graph-api)

And thought it might be the answer but then seen the question was old and another answer mentioned it is not longer correct.

appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the value returned by `builder.build().toString();`?

Comment: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!oGPk1QiHg0-cWO0SedDggamo9F8d5QBHt0u0jdBZpbrerRRWy_KmRoKq8n5FVxm9/items/012NNVL45G4TC23JTXOJCLC3JKIBFZQRFO/workbook](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!oGPk1QiHg0-cWO0SedDggamo9F8d5QBHt0u0jdBZpbrerRRWy_KmRoKq8n5FVxm9/items/012NNVL45G4TC23JTXOJCLC3JKIBFZQRFO/workbook) If i copy and paste the string to the Graph explorer using the same user, i get proper 200 response while in the app it returns 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i was not aware using sample code for the V2 (active-directory-android-native-**v2**-master) while the graph explorer (which was working) used V1.

There is a great "getting started" tutorial for the V1 sample code (active-directory-android-master) here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-android

Sample code seems quite the same only for V1.

When using the tutorial, i needed to find the required permissions for the command i was trying to use, in addition to the one mentioned at the tutorial.

I used the next link to get the permissions for the items:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get

I also added the permissions mentioned at the [Graph Exlorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) since as noted, the command i was trying to use worked there.

Since the permissions at the Azure site was not written the same (e.g. Files.Read is written as "Read user files") i used the next link to translate:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

Luckily i did not need to use any admin permissions, which would have complicated the registration to the app

Hopes this helps any struggled newbie like me :)

If anything from what i wrote not correct or you think i should add something, please let me know at the comments below and i will try to update

BTW - i used the [Graph Exlorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to detect the files & Drive ID items i needed

Comment: You can mark you reply as answer, so anyone else can be more convenient retrieval.