# Microsoft Graph API - Office 365 Access SharePoint Nested Folder Items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I was shared access to a SharePoint folder on our Office 365 site.

The folder is deeply nested. Something like:

```
http://mycorp.sharepoint.com

Our Docs > Marketing > Company > Images
```

Inside the "Images" folder are a list of JPGs.

How can I use the Graph API to access this deeply nested folder?

I've tried something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycorp.sharepoint.com:/Documents/Marketing/Company/Images:/Items
```

I feel I'm close but I'm just not sure how to access the nested folder structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format for referencing a path looks like this:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root:/{folder path}:/children
```

Using your example we have the following:

1. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root` returns the root site of your SharePoint tenant.
2. /`drive/root` returns default `Drive` for the `Site`. In this case, `/Documents` isn't actually a "folder", it's the default Drive for your root SharePoint
3. `:{folder path}:` should be replaced by the path to the folder you're looking for. In this case `/Marketing/Company/Images`. The first `:` operator tells SharePoint to treat the following string as a file path. The second `:` tells SharePoint where the file path string ends.
4. `/children` returns a list of `DriveItem` resources within the folder.

So you're complete URI should look something like this:

```
/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root:/Marketing/Company/Images:/children
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm able to see the data through the Graph Explorer. Can I not use "Application" authorization to view in my App with a Bearer Token? I've assigned the following App Level: Read managed metadata;Read and write items and lists in all site collections;Have full control of all site collections;Read items in all site collections;Read and write items in all site collections

Comment: I'm referencing this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878044/ms-graph-api-onedrive-resource-not-found Just wasn't sure if that's still up to date

Comment: That is no longer the case. You can see what scopes you need in the Graph Documentation: [`/children`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children) for example requires one of the following: `Files.Read.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Sites.Read.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: Thanks! So inside the Azure Portal => Microsoft Graph API => Are these correct? 1) Read and write files in all site collections

2) Read files in all site collections

3) Create, edit, and delete items and lists in all site collections

4) Have full control of all site collections

Comment: Nevermind! Appreciate your help. I found this which shows the conversions: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

Comment: Are there special permissions needed to actually read the JPG from HttpClient? I can get a JSON list of each file, but when I try to read the webUrl I'm geting unauthorized.

Comment: I have the following enabled: `Read items in all site collections (preview)` `Read files in all site collections`

Comment: Just a note, I was able to use the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property to grab the Image as a Byte Array and go from there. Still unsure on `webUrl`

Comment: Ideally I would just be able to use my MVC site to slice and dice the graph endpoint, then just pipe the `webUrl` so I don't have to handle resizing or storing the image byte data.

Comment: There are techniques for this but they really belong as a separate set of questions.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks Marc. See here to sum up my above comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560362/microsoft-graph-api-read-office-365-sharepoint-list-and-pull-data-images