# Microsoft Graph API - Read Office 365 SharePoint List and Pull Data (Images)

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Refrencing the following post: [Microsoft Graph API - Office 365 Access SharePoint Nested Folder Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540406/microsoft-graph-api-office-365-access-sharepoint-nested-folder-items/49541641)

I'm able to get a list of Images via the Graph API. I have an MVC Azure App where I'm making these Graph API calls.

However when I try to access the Image via the `webUrl` property, I get access denied.

I've been able to get around this by using the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property which I can access, download it via `HttpClient` convert to Byte Array and transform into a Thumbnail.

However ideally I would just be able to use my MVC site to slice and dice the graph endpoint, then just pipe out `webUrl` so I don't have to handle resizing or storing the image byte data.

First, why is `webUrl` return Access Denied?

Second, what would the best approach to just pipe the Image URL through my MVC App?  I don't want to be responsible for housing/transforming the image. The data needs to be accessed publicly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this but given that you're looking to show a thumbnail, I'd take a look at [`/thumbnails`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_thumbnails) endpoint:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails
```

You can use this in conjunction with the `/content` endpoint to retrieve the binary itself:

```
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/{thumb-id}/{size}/content
```

As for what to do with the binary result, I typically Base64 encode it on the backend and return a Data URL to the client. You can also cache this result and have your method simply check for a valid cached copy before making a new request to Graph.

This works particularly well with Profile Photos and Thumbnails where the data is pretty small.

An example of how you might do this in C# using the .NET Graph Client SDK:

```cs
var imageStream = await graphClient.Me
    .Photo
    .Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    var base64pic = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    return "data:image;base64," + base64pic;
}
```

Comment: So does that mean I need to do a separate Graph request for each Image in the List?

Comment: Additionally, any thoughts on why `webUrl` is Access Denied? Also, can I not just expose the Image endpoint itself so I don't have to do any cache my side?

Comment: Making progress! So it turns out the thumbnail endpoint is public and I can just push that URL from my endpoint.

Comment: `webUrl` is used to open the document in an editor (i.e. open a .docx in Word Online). It requires that you authenticate as part of that process.